# Is it possible to test software with automation only and no manual testing?

Tags: interview

Without manual testing, can we perform automation testing? And how do we do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Straight to the point answer is NO. But as this is tagged as interview question, it is not intended for straight-forward answer, but for opening up a conversation about the topic.
Your interviewer wants to hear your opinion on the subject of "manual-vs-automation". Opinion should be based on pure experience, not by the book.

That being said, the answer is highly individual and it should show:

- your experience with both
- how well your point of view blends with their
- if you can help with their current project/challenges.

Answer (score 0):

This was tagged as an interview question, so it's likely meant to be vague by the interviewer to see how the interviewee can respond to vague situations or to gauge your experience of the different types of testing.

From the interviewer's perspective, it's possible they are looking for someone with stronger skills in "manual" or "automation." Ultimately, this should have been clarified in the job description or in discussions with the recruiter. The later in the process this clarity comes up just means you're wasting everyone's time!

It seems like they want someone with test automation experience and to understand how they go about setting up test automation.

The interviewer could also likely want to understand your stance between the two. Unfortunately, the industry likes to pit "manual vs automation" against each other in skill sets, roles, job titles, compensation, etc. This is unfortunate because there is no such competition between other roles in tech or in other jobs! This competition needs to go away as it does everyone a disservice!

They could also just want to gauge how you deal with vagueness.

From the interviewee's perspective, it's up to you to gain clarity when asked a vague question. Too many interviewees think they just need to answer the question as asked when in reality, you can ask questions back to gain clarity, to create a conversation!

When on the job, you are faced with vagueness all the time. Story and feature requirements are often vague, designs are vague, and your job is to clarify that in order to test. Vagueness creates bugs! If the designer or developer interprets the requirement one way, and you as a tester a different way, who's right? In my experience, this leads to bugs and when you encounter bugs, who's interpretation is correct? Don't just go with what the developer says or intepreted, have a discussion! Who wrote the requirements? Talk to them to understand their intention. You don't want to build the wrong thing, so by the time you find the bug, it's too late. How can you find this clarity sooner, before any code is written? This is where the term "shift-left" occurs.

How can you get clarity? Ask the following of the interviewer?

- Is this role geared towards mostly manual testing or mostly automation testing?
- Is there any test automation currently? Here you can answer how you can setup a test automation strategy or framework if you have that experience. Based on the question so far, it seems like this is what they are looking for. If you lack test automation skills, you likely aren't a fit for this job.
- Or, if you lack test automation skills, how can you learn this on the job? Do they offer training or mentoring?
- If they want more test automation, you can ask, do you have test automation currently set up? If so, how much? What part of the stack has test automation? If they have no test automation, again, go into your strategy on setting it up. If they have some, understand where they have gaps and how you'll fix those.

The short answer to "Without manual testing, can we perform automation testing? And how do we do that?" is, both yes and no. It depends. The classic QA answer! It really depends on the context, which is up to you to clarify.

Yes, it is possible, but not feasible.

No, it's not possible, as there is always some manual testing involved.

As an interviewer, if you answered with one of these, they are vague and I'd ask for more details. This goes to show that when asked this question, get clarity before you answer.

This is also the reason why this question is getting downvoted or getting comments for more clarity because those of us with a lot of experience know that context matters!

Ultimately, the interviewer has a problem they need solved and is trying to figure out how you can help solve their problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do only automation journalism, without manual
> journalism?
>
> Is it possible to do only automation medicine, without manual
> medicine?
>
> Is it possible to do only automation science, without manual science?
>
> Is it possible to do only automation text editing, without manual text
> editing?

How do these questions sound to you?
Do they trigger the phrase "there is no such thing as automation journalism, only journalism with the aid of tools to enhance the journalist capabilities"?

Answer (score 0):

You can skip manual testing, but the end product will suffer.

Each type of testing has its pros and cons; by skipping on manual testing, you're going to want to consider the tradeoffs, there are many factors here, but just 2 thoughts to conisder.

- Usability issues - You could automate checks such as colour blindness checks etc... but automated tests are not going to pick up all on usability issues, and a human performing tests will always be better at raising issues in terms of usability.
- Holes - Automated sripts cant off-script; they will test what the developer has designed them to test and as such there are likely to be holes. A human, can go off script, perform exploratory testing and is likely to find other issues that automated tests miss.